# How would I use to .xib file to make image placement fit iPhone 5 and 4 screens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I'm needing to use a .xib file to make sure that my images on my screen match both screen sizes. I would post images, but unfortunately my access is still limited on stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your problem?

Comment: Every time I place an image on the .xib canvas it looks fine on my iPhone 5, but moves when I test my app on my iPhone 4.

Comment: moves means? what you are trying to say, explain what happen when you test it on iPhone4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need do it programmatically as given below. Add following define statement to you `ProjectName-Prefix.pch` file so its available in all over the application.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-(double)568)<DBL_EPSILON)
```

and then in the ViewController, you can do something like:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
   //Set image(s) specific for iPhone5 to your ImageViews
} else {
  //This is iPhone4 or older therefore set appropriate images for 3.5" size
}
```